# How to store values of mySQL Time data type using Hibernate without conversion to mySQL server timezone?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My mySQL server timezone is set to UTC.  I have a Time column in the mySQL db which stores times in the format hh:mm:ss. I use Hibernate to access my database. When I insert a time (java.sql.Time) through a Hibernate query, it automatically gets converted to UTC. For example, my timezone is EDT so the time stored in the db gets is input time + 5 hours. How can I store the time as is?  Do I have to store it as a string? I don't want to change any global hibernate properties.

Comment: There is one detail in behavior which you did not mention, namely that when you read your data from MySQL back into Java, the timezone should again get shifted back from UTC to the timezone of your JVM.  Can you add more detail on why you think you need to do what you suggest?

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the time isn't getting shifted back to my timezone. If I create a time, say "00:00:00", it gets stored as "05:00:00". When I use an endpoint to get the time back, the time is "05:00:00". This isn't the case with a datetime object though(works as expected). @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Are you storing your dates/times as text?  Don't do that.

Comment: No, I'm storing it as a Time object. I observe this behaviour only on my machine. The times get read back correctly on another machine.